# Google cloud messaging payload iOS

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement Google cloud messaging in iOS app, the app receives the notification when payload is exactly in the following format

```
{"to": "/topics/mytopic", "notification" : {"body" : "my notification"}}
```

I would also like to send custom data along with the body for example

```
{"to": "/topics/mytopic", "notification": {"body": "my notification"}, "data": {"mykey": "myvalue"}}
```

But iOS never receives any notifications containing anything other than that format. I need to send custom data along with the notification please let me know how it is done.

Comment: So for the notification, you can try to use `body` as well as `title`. You can change your `body` tag to `title` and then put the custom data to `body` tag. For more details, please refer here:https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client#http_post_request